# OutOfMemoryError on Android devices using jsoup 1.6.0

Tags: android, jsoup

What i am doing is getting the app details from Google play and checking for updates through a service that runs once a day.

Its working fine on some small devices like Nexus S but in Samsung Note 1 its getting a crash

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:91)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:201)
at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.readToByteBuffer(DataUtil.java:96)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:408)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:364)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:143)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:132)
at com.gv.mface360e.UpdateCheckService.web_update(UpdateCheckService.java:89)
at com.gv.mface360e.UpdateCheckService.checkForApplicationsUpdate(UpdateCheckService.java:49)
at com.gv.mface360e.UpdateCheckService.access$0(UpdateCheckService.java:45)
at com.gv.mface360e.UpdateCheckService$1.run(UpdateCheckService.java:39)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I dont know the reason or how to avoid this Plz help me.

Comment: what i suggest you to write a simple PHP script in that put the latest version of your app, and host it on a free server like 000webhost, create a JSON API for getting the version of App and compare it to yours present app versionCode every day.

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of jsoup have reduced memory usage. Possibly related to your case https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/132 . Why don't you upgrade to 1.8?